# Debian 8 apt-get update showing 404 Not Found

Tags: debian, apt

I got the following output every time I run `apt-get update` on my Debian 8.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                      
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                
Fetched 164 kB in 3s (47.0 kB/s)                                       
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**And this is what I have in** `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

**And this is the output of** `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu jessie main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu jessie main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jessie main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jessie main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jessie main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jessie main
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie main
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie main
```

Comment: Looking at http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/dists, it seems that debian distributions have been removed from the server. Removing the server from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` will remove the messages, but you still won't get updates on the said packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the file which contain :

```
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie main
```

Under your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` then update :

```
apt update
```

If you have one file , you can comment/remove other urls:

```
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu jessie main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu jessie main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jessie main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jessie main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jessie main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jessie main
# deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie main

deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie main
```

Comment: @sourcejedi php is still supported by Ondřej Surý on Debian and Ubuntu. Also the repository provide php5.6 for debian 9

Comment: I see, so they still provide updates, it's just that they moved the repo. Thanks for your patient explaination.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to maintain a disaster recovery plan for this server AND you preferred not to rely on backups of the root fs, you might also want to start using `jessie-backports` to provide the package for `certbot`. But that's nitpicking. https://wiki.debian.org/LetsEncrypt

Answer (score 2):

So this shows you are successfully downloading repo updates from Debian Jessie[*], but not two of your third-party repos.

Based on information pointed out by other commenters, it looks like these particular repos no longer support your operating system.

[*] Debian 8 is currently "oldstable", and has been so for nearly one year.  After June 2018, it will be supported by the [Debian LTS project](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) instead of the original Debian security team.  If you plan to stay with Debian LTS, please make sure you're familiar with what this means.  In particular "a few packages will not be supported in the LTS version of the release, primarily some web-based applications which cannot be supported for the additional timeframe. The tool `check-support-status` from the package `debian-security-support` helps to detect such unsupported packages."

(It might also be relevant to consider that `backports` will also stop getting updates.  However `backports` is already not officially supported by the security team, i.e. there were not the same promises in the first place).

---

One possibility is that you would want to remove the package versions installed specifically from a PPA, and then switch to a different source which supports your operating system.

You should probably take care to make sure that you have entirely switched to the new source, and don't have any packages still installed from the PPA which you are trying to replace.  (This is less important in the strange case where it's really the same repo, but the location where the repo is hosted has been changed).

I found the following blog post about how to identify packages installed from a PPA which you have since removed:

[Remove a PPA and roll back changes in Debian | Flynsarmy](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/05/remove-a-ppa-and-roll-back-changes-in-debian/)

via searching 'debian uninstall PPA', and then 'debian "ppa-purge"' (when I got results for Ubuntu telling me about `ppa-purge`).

---

> If you’re a Ubuntu user, you may be familiar with ppa-purge. It’s a handy little automated script to remove a PPA and roll back the version of any apps installed from that PPA. Debian doesn’t have this nicety by default but there’s a relatively simple way to get something close.

> Firstly, remove your PPA from /etc/apt/sources.list or from the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory.

> Do an update:

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```

> Find any packages that are now obsolete:

> ```
> aptitude search '?obsolete'
> ```
>
> For me this returned the following:
>
> ```
> # aptitude search '?obsolete'
> i A libmysqlclient18      - MySQL database client library                                                                           
> i A mysql-client-5.5      - MySQL database client binaries                                                                          
> i A mysql-server-5.5      - MySQL database server binaries and system database setup                                                
> i A mysql-server-core-5.5 - MySQL database server binaries                                                                          
> i A ruby-passenger        - Rails and Rack support for Apache2 and Nginx
> ```
>
> Now just remove the listed packages with apt-get remove and reinstall
> as necessary. It’s not quite the automated tool that ppa-purge is, but
> it’s a pretty good start.

Comment: thanks, I do get a list of packages from aptitude search '?obsolete', can I just remove those packages and it won't have any impact on my running server?

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I have squeeze and stretch lying around and have `buster` in my mind.  Purged lecture about `oldoldstable`, thanks.

Comment: I beg to differ re the idiot part, it’s easy to get mixed up with the releases ;-).

Comment: @sourcejedi I removed all packages from the list i got from aptitude search '?obsolete', but when I ran apt-get update, i got the same output as in my question.

Comment: These are instructions to remove a PPA. "Firstly, remove your PPA from /etc/apt/sources.list or from the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory." If you have sucessfully removed a PPA, you will not see errors from that PPA anymore :-). But I suspect you do want certbot installed from somewhere, so my advice may not actually be very helpful. Sorry for making a mess here.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem after correct in sources-lists. What was solve my problem:

1. Delete all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` excluding

   - `nginx.list` containing `deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian jessie nginx`
   - `vesta.list` containing `deb http://apt.vestacp.com/stretch/ stretch vesta`
2. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to:

   ```
    deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
    deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
    deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main contrib non-free
   ```
3. After that `apt update && apt upgrade` works well